# Past perfect continuous for a non continuous action

Tags: perfect-continuous

http://www.eltbase.com/get_quiz.php?id=22

Level 3 - Narrative tenses quiz : a creepy story

> *So who...or what...______________ around upstairs?*

The options are: 1) had walked 2) walked 3) had been walking 4) was walking

The answer is **had been walking**  but not had walked why? It was not a continuous activity is it to show the surprise and the fear they have now  because it was not Sarah's mother who walked .

Comment: may be the continuous means only recently

Comment: I guess this never got answered satisfactorily because the question is so unclear unless someone actually takes the test. You need the context of the other questions in it.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I took up the quiz and got all correct! The answer is in the title! Filling blanks will make a *story*.

Now, the story is in *past* and therefore, the event you are talking about will take *the past perfect continuous form.*

Why?

Well, check the question number 6 that says, *"someone **walking**."* It is a present continuous. After a little while, it becomes past but you should keep the **act of 'walking' intact**. Said that, *was walking* and *had been walking* are the two options to choose from. But if you think a bit more, you'd choose something that talks about the 'distant past' which means 'had been' over 'was'.

Comment: yes what  surprises me is the continuous aspect At the time of speaking the hearing had been finished, it only lasted a very few time so we can use continuous ? does it mean  who had been walking until  Sarah's mother arrived , in that case I understand the use of the continous form

Comment: Yes, what they heard was 'walking', the continuous event. Walked/had walked is thus out of choice. 'Was' won't fit there as it does not talk about a distant past in this context. @user5577

Answer (score 0):

I got 9 out of 10. In number 3 I chose "invited" which is also a correct answer. 
Anyway about your question, "had been walking" is correct because it's connected to number 6 which"someone is walking".

Comment: Please, all of you, recognise that the suggested interpretations simply are not justified; neither by particular circumstances nor by general rules of grammar.

The point here is that the details on which the OQ relied, make no sense.

If you doubt that please, explain in detail how you see the problem…

Answer (score 0):

Uh… *Had been walking* is fine and did you notice, none of the other options is wrong?

Who had walked around upstairs?

Who walked around upstairs?

Who had been walking around upstairs?

Who was walking around upstairs?

Any of those should be accepted without comment.